# The coset/quotient space of a normal subgroup of a topological group is a topological group

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, solution-verification, topological-groups

I'm following Lee's "Introduction to Topological Manifolds" and

> **3-16.** If $\Gamma$ is a normal subgroup of the topological group $G$, show that the coset space $G/\Gamma$ is a topological group.

Below I provide my solution/proof of this statement. My confusion is that the author offers a hint pointing to previous exercises which show that (a) a finite product of open maps is open and (b) the quotient map induced by a continuous group action is an open map. Nowhere in my proof am I using either of these facts, so am I going wrong somewhere? I seemingly am proving the result using just the notion of "passing to the quotient."

### My Proof

Let $\Gamma$ be a normal subgroup of topological group $G$. Then the usual inversion and group multiplication operations on $G$, $$ \iota: G\rightarrow G \text{ given by } \iota\left(g\right) = g^{-1} $$ and $$ \mu: G \times G \rightarrow G \text{ given by } \mu\left(\left(g,h\right)\right) = gh, $$ are continuous. We know from elementary abstract algebra that since $\Gamma$ is normal, the quotient group $G/\Gamma$ is itself a group under the operations $$ \overline{\iota}: G/\Gamma \rightarrow G/\Gamma \text{ given by } \overline{\iota}\left(g\Gamma\right) = g^{-1}\Gamma $$ and $$ \overline{\mu}: G/\Gamma \times G/\Gamma \rightarrow G/\Gamma \text{ given by } \overline{\mu}\left(\left(g\Gamma, h\Gamma\right)\right) = \left(gh\right)\Gamma. $$ To show that $G/\Gamma$ is a topological group, it remains to show that these operations are continuous with respect to the quotient topology on $G/\Gamma$. Lastly, let $\pi: G \rightarrow G/\Gamma$ be the standard projection map $\pi\left(g\right) = g\Gamma$ for $g\in G$.

First, the inversion map. Let $$\psi = \pi \circ \iota: G \rightarrow G/\Gamma \text{ be given by } \psi\left(g\right) = g^{-1}\Gamma $$ which is clearly continuous as the composition of two continuous maps. Then it's easy to see that $\psi$ is constant on the fibers of $\pi$:
$$ \pi\left(x\right) = \pi\left(y\right) \iff x\Gamma = y\Gamma
\iff x = \gamma y \text{ for some } \gamma \in \Gamma $$
(since $\Gamma$ is a normal subgroup!) hence $$ \psi\left(x\right) = x^{-1}\gamma = \left(\gamma y\right)^{-1}\Gamma = y^{-1} \gamma^{-1} \Gamma = y^{-1} \Gamma = \psi\left(y\right).$$ Thus, $\psi$ passes to the quotient to give rise to a (unique) continuous map $\overline{\psi}: G/\Gamma \rightarrow G/\Gamma$ such that $ \overline{\psi} \circ \pi = \pi \circ \iota = \psi$; it is obvious that $\overline{\psi} = \overline{\iota}$, the inversion map of the group $G/\Gamma$, so inversion is continuous.

Next, the multiplication map. The procedure is very similar, except the spaces are different, so I will use similar notation. Let $$ \psi = \pi \circ \mu: G \times G \rightarrow G/\Gamma $$ which is continuous as the composition of continuous maps. Define $\pi \times \pi: G\times G \rightarrow G/\Gamma \times G/\Gamma$ as the product of "two copies" of the quotient map on $G$; this map is a quotient map, being surjective and continuous (as the product of two continuous maps). Then $\psi$ is constant on the fibers of $\pi\times \pi$: $$ \pi \times \pi\left(\left(g,h\right)\right) = \pi\times\pi\left(\left(g',h'\right)\right) \implies g = \gamma g', h = h' \overline{\gamma} \text{ for some } \gamma, \overline{\gamma} \in \Gamma.$$ Then $$ \psi\left(\left(g,h\right)\right) = gh\Gamma = \gamma g'h' \overline{\gamma} \Gamma = g'h' \Gamma = \psi\left(\left(g',h'\right)\right) $$ where we used the fact that $\Gamma$ is normal to "absorb" $\gamma$ and $\overline{\gamma}$. Thus, $\psi$ passes to the quotient and induces a (unique) continuous map $\overline{\psi}: G/\Gamma \times G/\Gamma \rightarrow G/\Gamma $ such that $ \overline{\psi} \circ \left(\pi \times \pi\right) = \pi \circ \mu = \psi $. Then clearly $\overline{\psi} = \overline{\mu}$, the multiplication map of the group $G/\Gamma$, and so this multiplication is continuous.

Thus, $G/\Gamma$ is a topological group since both inversion and the group multiplication operation are continuous (with respect to the quotient topology).

**Question** Are there any major gaps in my proof? The hints about "open maps" is making me second-guess my logic.

Comment: Surjective and continuous is not the same as being a quotient map; you also need the extra condition that the topology on the target coincides with the quotient topology induced by the map in question. Being an open map helps (why?) so I think you may have to elaborate on why the quotient $(G\times G)/(\Gamma\times\Gamma)$ is homeomorphic to $(G/\Gamma)\times (G/\Gamma)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come back to studying these concepts and finally understand what I was missing here. I will correct this proof for the multiplication operation.

First I will show that the map $p=\pi \times \pi: G \times G \rightarrow \left(G/\Gamma\right) \times \left(G/\Gamma\right)$ is a quotient map. It is obviously surjective and continuous, as the product of two surjective and continuous maps. (Here is what I missed previously:) The quotient map $\pi: G\rightarrow G/\Gamma$ is open (from Problem 3-15a) and so $p$ is open as the finite product of open maps (from Problem 1), and so $p$ is a quotient map.

The fibers of $p$ are of the form $$ p^{-1}\left(a\Gamma, b\Gamma\right) = a\Gamma \times b\Gamma. $$ Note that the mapping $\pi \circ \mu: G\times G \rightarrow G/\Gamma$ is constant on these fibers: if $\left(x,y\right), \left(u,v\right) \in p^{-1}\left(a\Gamma, b\Gamma\right) =a\Gamma \times b\Gamma$, then $x = \gamma u, y = v\gamma'$ for some $\gamma, \gamma'\in \Gamma$, and so $$ \pi\circ \mu\left(x,y\right) = xy\Gamma = \gamma uv \gamma' \Gamma = uv \Gamma = \pi \circ \mu\left(u,v\right) $$ since $\Gamma$ is a normal subgroup. Thus is is constant on these fibers. $\pi \circ \mu$ is continuous as the composition of continuous maps. Hence we can pass this to the quotient to obtain the continuous map $\overline{\psi}:\left(G/\Gamma\right) \times \left(G/\Gamma\right) \rightarrow G/\Gamma$ given by $\overline{\psi}\left(a\Gamma, b\Gamma\right) = ab\Gamma$ which is exactly the multiplication map on $\left(G/\Gamma\right)\times \left(G/\Gamma\right)$, hence the latter is continuous.

Thus, both operations are continuous and so $G/\Gamma$ is a topological group.